# Using .svg file for sprite but it's not working

Tags: svg, sprite

I had a .png sprite, which worked, but I switched  to .svg and it's shrinking the total image to the height (24px). Here's my site: http://www.bethalessi.com/ You can see it in the sidebar in that empty space. My code:

```
ul.social {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 4em;
}   
.social li {
display: inline-block;
}   
.social a {
display: block;
width: 28px;
height: 24px;
background: url(assets/images/social.svg) no-repeat;
}
```

If I change the height to 336px (the height of the file), it shows correct size but then repeats the image for each link.

How do I use .svg file to make a sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your SVG a little.  Change line 4 from:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 28 336" enable-background="new 0 0 28 336" xml:space="preserve">
```

to

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="28" height="336" enable-background="new 0 0 28 336" xml:space="preserve">
```

Your current version of the SVG, with the `viewBox` attribute, tells the browser that you want the SVG scaled to fit the parent container.  Which is the 28x24 box.

The altered version makes the SVG a fixed size (28x336), so it should now behave similarly to a bitmap sprite sheet.

Comment: Yes! It appears now. But now when I hover it disappears, rather than showing the other icons in a different color that I have on the sprite. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: It's because your SVG now seems to have lost its hover variants.  It just has the black ones.

Comment: Ah, yes, it was directing to a different .svg. That did it, thank you.